# How to Convert a String into a user defined object reference

Tags: java, object, reference

```
public class Country {      
    public static void main(String[] args) {    
        String country_name;
        String capital;
        String iso_numeric;
        String iso2;
        String iso3;

        String[] name = new String[] {"united_state", "united_kingdom", "france", "germany", "canada"};

        for(int i = 0; i < name.length; i++) {
            Country name[i] = new Country();
        }

    }

}
```

Hi, I have the above code:

What I want to do is to automate the creation of the object references of Country class, so by the end I should have something looks like:

```
Country united_state = new Country();       
Country united_kingdom = new Country();     
Country france = new Country();     
Country germany = new Country();        
Country canada = new Country();
```

However, I'm getting error at: 
    Country name[i] = new Country();

Thanks in advance for your time and help.

Comment: Where have you instantiated Country [] array ?

Comment: The array name cannot refer to both String and Country simultaneously.  This code is simply wrong.

Comment: since you didn't post the error message I assume you didn't read or understood it?

Comment: This sounds like a PHP or JavaScript approach ...

IMHO you should do it with an `Enum Country`, and - if needed - let that enum have a `private String countryName`, so you could have a method like `public Country getCountryByCountryName(String countryName)`.

Comment: simply impossible!

Comment: why do you need named objects ? just create array of object of Country. and assign country name to each one, either by function call or constructor.

Comment: @ArcticLord, what is it that is impossible?

Comment: @OleV.V. The code of the OP tries to create vars with names that are constructed within the code itself. With java this is simply impossible.

Comment: Thanks, @ArcticLord, for explaining. If that was the intension, it’s certainly impossible. Rather use a map: `myMap.put(name[i], new Country());`. Then again, the enum I suggested in my answer already gives you the lookup functionality the map would provide: `Country united_states = Country.valueOf("united_states");.`

Answer (score 0):

You appear to want this:

```
public class Country {
    private final String name;
    // Add these later
    // private final String capital;
    // private final String iso_numeric;
    // private final String iso2;
    //  private final String iso3;

    public Country(String name) { 
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getName() { return this.name; }
}
```

Once you have this, you can do this:

```
    String[] name = new String[] {"united_state", "united_kingdom", "france", "germany", "canada"};

    List<Country> countries = new ArrayList<Country>();
    for(int i = 0; i < name.length; i++) {
        countries.add(new Country(name[i]));
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks to me like what you want is an enum:

```
public enum Country {

    united_states("United States", "Washington", "840", "us", "usa"), 
    united_kingdom("United Kingdom", "London", (* etc */)),
    france(/* etc */), 
    germany(/* etc */),
    canada(/* etc */);

    String country_name;
    String capital;
    String iso_numeric;
    String iso2;
    String iso3;

    private Country(String country_name, String capital, String iso_numeric, String iso2, String iso3) {
        this.country_name = country_name;
        this.capital = capital;
        this.iso_numeric = iso_numeric;
        this.iso2 = iso2;
        this.iso3 = iso3;
    }

}
```

To get an array of all countries, use `Country.values()`. Go read the tutorials on Java enums to learn more.